# Exercise 1.1.(c) in Hartshorne's Deformation Theory

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory

[Exercise 1.1.(c)](https://books.google.com/books?id=bwhEX01JlXkC&pg=PA7) in Hartshorne's Deformation Theory:

> Over an algebraically closed field $k$, we define a *curve* in $\mathbb P^2_k$ to be the closed subscheme, defined by a homogeneous polynomial $f(x,y,z)$ of degree $d$ in the coordinate ring $S=k[x,y,z]$.
>
> (c) For any finitely generated $k$-algebra $A$, we define a *family* of curves of degree $d$ in $\mathbb P^2$ over $A$ to be a closed subscheme $X\subseteq\mathbb P^2_A$, flat over $A$, whose fibers above closed points of $\mathrm{Spec}\,A$ are curves in $\mathbb P^2$. Show that the ideal $I_X\subseteq A[x,y,z]$ is generated by a single homogeneous polynomial $f$ of degree $d$ in $A[x,y,z]$.

My attempts: the condition on fibers above closed points is equivalent to the condition that for any $\mathfrak m\in\mathrm{Specm}\,A$ the ideal $(I_X,\mathfrak m)/\mathfrak m$ is principal. Equivalently, for any $\mathfrak m$ there is $f_{\mathfrak m}\in I_X$ such that $I_X\subset (f_{\mathfrak m},\mathfrak m)$. Also, it is clearly sufficient to prove that $I_X$ contains a homogeneous element of degree $d$.

Comment: Here is MSE copy: [Exercise 1.1.(c) in Hartshorne's Deformation Theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2640048)

Comment: I do not have the book in front of me, but it sounds to me like the formulation above is false.  Certainly $I_X$ is generated as an $A[x,y,z]$-module by the degree-$d$ graded component $I_{X,d} := I_X\cap A[x,y,z]_d$.  Also the $A$-module $I_{X,d}$ is locally free of rank $1$.  However, if the class group of $A$ is nontrivial, I believe that $I_{X,d}$ can be non-free.  Thus, although $I_X$ is generated by a single homogeneous polynomial *locally on $\text{Spec}\ A$*, this need not be true globally.

Comment: @Jason Starr: now I quote the book verbatim.

Comment: That formulation is false.

Comment: Indeed, it is. And the local version is sufficient for the rest of the exercise (which, by the way, aims to show that the complete linear system of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(d)$ is the Hilbert scheme of curves of degree $d$ in $\mathbb{P}^2$ where the universal family is the tautological one).

Comment: @Jason Starr: could you explain why $I_X$ is generated by $I_{X,d}$?

Comment: I've learned that if $\mathrm{Spec}\, A$ is a smooth variety and $X$ is reduced (so that it is a Weil divisor) then we can use the fact that $h^1(\mathbb P^2,\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^2})=0$ to prove that the result is locally true (see Mumford's Lectures on curves on an algebraic surface, Lecture 13, Proposition 3 or Exercise III.12.6 in Hartshorne).

Comment: Reading the Lecture 15, I found a proof in the general case. Consider a closed point $x\in\mathbb P^2\times\mathrm{Spec}\, A$ lying over $\mathfrak m\subset A$, and let $I_x\subset\mathcal O_x$ be the ideal defining $X$ at $x$. We have $(I_x,\mathfrak m)=(f,\mathfrak m)$ for some $f\in I_x$. Consider the exact sequence $0\to I_x/(f)\to\mathcal O_x/(f)\to\mathcal O_x/I_x\to 0$. Using the flatness of $X$ we obtain that $I_x/(f)\otimes A/\mathfrak m=0$. It follows that $I_x/(f)=0$.

Comment: @danneks, Hi, I'm not too sure I follow; firstly, I think on $\mathcal{O}_x$, you've lost so much information that I'm not quite sure how you can conclude? Secondly, to me the statement $I_x/ f\otimes A / \mathfrak{m} = 0$ doesn't seem quite helpful, as all it's saying is that on the fibre that $x$ is in, say $X_p$, the ideal of $I_x$ in the local ring of $x$ in $X_p$, say $\mathcal{O}_{X_p, x}$ is principally generated, which, if $X_p$ is nonsingular, already follows since the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{X_p, x}$ is a DVR?

Answer (score 17):

I agree. Thanks for discovering the error. And by the way there is another error on the same page, line -1, there is a -2 that should be a -4.
Robin Hartshorne

Answer (score 8):

I am just writing my comment as an answer.  The stated exercise is true *locally on $\text{Spec}\ A$*, however it is not true globally.  For instance, let $A$ be $k[s,t,u,v]/\langle st-uv,u+v-1\rangle$.  Let $J$ denote the ideal in $A$ generated by $s$ and $u$.  This has a presentation, $$A^{\oplus 2}\xrightarrow{M} A^{\oplus 2} \xrightarrow{q} J \to 0,$$
where $q(f,g)$ equals $fs-gu$ and where $M$ is the following $2\times 2$ matrix, $$M = \left[\begin{array}{cc}u & t \\ s & v \end{array} \right].$$  Denote by $I_{X,1}$ the image of the $A$-module homomorphism, $$\phi:A^{\oplus 2} \to A[x,y,z]_1,\ \  (f,g) \mapsto (fs-gu)x + (fv-gt)y.$$  The ideal $I_X\subset A[x,y,z]$ generated by $I_{X,1}$ is a radical homogeneous ideal whose corresponding zero scheme, $X\subset \mathbb{P}^2_A$, is flat over $\text{Spec}\ A$ of relative degree $1$.  The $A$-module $I_{X,1}$ is locally free of rank $1$, isomorphic to $J$.  Yet the ideal $I_X$ is not principal since the $A$-module $I_{X,1}\cong J$ is not free.